# Haproxy - forward request to S3 hosted site

Tags: amazon-s3, haproxy

I have extremely low knowledge on haproxy. Was testing out a configuration where

S3 hosted website (route 53 alias) - content.mydomain.com
URL landing on haproxy - www.mydomain.com/getfiles/

Is it possible to redirect reroute www.mydomain.com/getfiles/ to content.mydomain.com (s3 hosted website).

I was able to redirect it to another application running on the same server with the below mentioned config

```
  acl display-s3-content path_beg /getfiles/
  use_backend my-content if display-s3-content

backend my-content   
  reqrep ^([^\ ]*)\ (.*) \1\ /path/\2   
  server test www.mycomain.com:1936
```

but when i try to redirect it to s3 hosted site, it does not work. Below is the backend for the not working config

```
  reqrep ^([^\ ]*)\ (.*) \1\ /path/\2
  server test1 content.mydomain.com
```

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't "redirecting," it is "forwarding."

Comment: So, if a request comes in with a path beginning with `/getfiles/`, you want to send that request to the bucket. I can post an answer illustrating how that is done, but first, I need to know what you want to do with the `/getfiles/` at the beginning of the path so that we look for the right path in the bucket.  Remove it? Replace it with something else?  Also, what version of HAProxy?

Comment: hey michael, i will be glad to know the right approach on it, haproxy - 1.5.2 and i believe will need to remove it as i guess currently s3 is throwing 301 because it has to be content.mydomain.com to display the content. thanks!

Comment: What about the path?  Where, for example, would the file called `/getfiles/test.jpg` be, in the bucket?   Still at `/getfiles/test.jpg`? Or just `/test.jpg`? Or another path?

Comment: It is just /test.jpg, content.mydomain.com points to bucket content.mycomain.com and index document is index.html, followed this [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html). I am coming from www.mydomain.com/getfiles.

Comment: reqirep ^Host: Host:\ content.mydomain.com server test1 content.mydomain.com / worked for me, but i will wait for your explanation on the approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you noted in comments, this works:

```
reqirep ^Host: Host:\ content.mydomain.com
```

The idea is to set the `Host` header to the value that S3 expects.

A somewhat cleaner approach is this:

```
http-request set-header Host content.mydomain.com
```

I say "better" because it uses a newer/better/safer mechanism for header manipulation, but it is fundamentally accomplishing the same purpose: changing the request header to what the destination server (S3) expects.  Using the `http-request` approach is safer/cleaner because it is "smarter" about how it manipulates the request -- it's much easier to completely break the protocol using `req[i]rep` than it is with `http-request`.

Originally, you asked about `/getfiles/test.jpg` mapping to `/test.jpg` in the bucket.  This rewrite is very easy and clean in HAProxy 1.6 and later:

```
http-request set-path %[path,regsub(^/getfiles,)]
```

...but in 1.5 you have to use `reqirep` since the `regsub` (regex substitution) converter isn't available:

```
reqirep ^([^\ :]+)\ +/getfiles(.*) \1\ \2
```

This matches the `GET` (`HEAD`, `POST`, etc.)  line from the request and removes the extra `/getfiles` from the path.  Including the `:` in the exclusion pattern prevents it from matching any other header.  A similar pattern can be used to add a prefix (such as a release version, etc.) before sending the request to S3.

Comment: which file is this http-request statement added?

Comment: @fuzzi these directives are set up in the HAProxy [config file](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#2.1l). It is typically found at `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`, but that path may change across different installations.

Answer (score 2):

I posted a sample config here as well.  This config will serve up:

`http://<haproxy>/foo/index.html`

with `index.html` sitting on S3.

https://gist.github.com/amslezak/6573767376860ed59a74878fbff6e61f

Comment: can i forward https traffic to the same backend too?

Comment: If the haproxy binds to :443 with an SSL cert, it should forward to s3 transparently.  Here's a quick idea on how to bind 443 + cert: https://serversforhackers.com/c/using-ssl-certificates-with-haproxy